# Find string based on index

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to find the string that comes after a known string:
string_n=1....
so I am trying to determine the index of "n=" to then find out which number of experiment it is (in this case 1). How would I do that?
This is my approach so far but it does not work I get NA for exp_number:

```
library(stringr)

for (i in length(names)){

  pos_of_n = str_which(pattern = '=', names[i], fixed = TRUE)

  substring = names[I]

  exp_number = substring[pos_of_n[1]+1]

  exp_name <- paste("exp", toString(exp_number,width=NULL))

}
```

Comment: Can you give examples of input strings and the output which would be extracted? Seems like maybe this could be done with gsub e.g. `gsub('.*string_n=(\\d+).*', 'exp \\1', x)`

Comment: The strings look somewhat like a file path: D:Maj_stats_n1_pooled2019-0918_screen_n=3_T_Template.csv
So in this case n is 3 but sometimes n is 1 and I want to make a string that says which experiment it is so in this case exp3. So I want to search for "n=" and find the next character (the "3") and make the name tostring("exp"+character after =)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your data looks somewhat like the strings below.

```
library(stringr)
strings <- c('exp n=1', 'exp n=2 more information...')

# Returns a matrix. First column is complete match, second the first
# set of parentheses, third the second set of parentheses -- which is
# the one we want.
exp_numbers <- str_match(strings, '(n\\=)(\\d+)')[,3]
# [1] "1" "2"
paste0("Exp", exp_numbers)
# [1] "Exp1" "Exp2"

# Using the data string you provided
strings <- c(' D:Maj_stats_n1_pooled2019-0918_screen_n=3_T_Template.csv')
exp_numbers <- stringr::str_match(strings, '(n\\=)(\\d+)')[,3]
labels <- paste0("Exp", exp_numbers)
labels
#> [1] "Exp3"
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not quite get your answer . My strings look like this: D:Maj_stats_n1_pooled2019-0918_screen_n=3_T_Template.csv  and I want to find out the number that will come after n= to make a new string "Exp"+ number

Comment: I've added an example using your string.